# Is there a way to simplify the detail of grease pencil line art procedurally?

Tags: grease-pencil, freestyle, lineart

I'd like to have the line art set up to dynamically change the level of detail picked out by the lines, e.g. based on distance to the camera. The illustrative example is a beveled edge: when the object is close and large on the screen, there should be lines picking out the bevel, but when the object is far away there should only be at most a single line picking out the edge generally. Ideally this would not be entirely based on camera distance--consider looking at the beveled edge from an oblique angle, the lines also appear cluttered. A quick example image:
[image: Example of default cube, beveled, with line art modifier next to rotated and more distant cubes showing undesired lines too close to each other, and a rough example of a preferred outcome]

Simply adjusting, say, the crease angle isn't quite right--I don't want either all the lines on a beveled edge or none of the lines, I want an intermediate level of detail: there is an edge, but we don't need to show it's beveled. I'm aware there's some support for this level-of-detail like control with freestyle, e.g. the sphere radius setting. But I'd much prefer a native grease pencil solution. I'm sort of envisioning something that would average out two strokes if/where they trace  substantially the same path next to each other, as that addresses the problem directly: I don't want what are effectively multiple copies of a line all drawn on top of each other and cluttering the line art. But I don't see how to go about implementing something like that. The simplify-merge modifier is conceptually almost it, but I want to merge strokes not vertices.